# Java 8 comparator not working

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-stream, comparator

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file
I have this piece of code to compare POJOs, but the compartor seems not to work because lastDeviceEvent and firstDeviceEvent are the same object with the same ID

```
DeviceEvent lastDeviceEvent = null;
        DeviceEvent firstDeviceEvent = null;

        try {       

            lastDeviceEvent = deviceEvents
                            .stream()
                            .filter (o -> o.getId().equals(deviceId))
                            .sorted(comparing((DeviceEvent de) -> de.getId()).reversed())
                            .findFirst().get();



            firstDeviceEvent = deviceEvents
                    .stream()
                    .filter (o -> o.getId().equals(deviceId)) 
                    .sorted(comparing((DeviceEvent de) -> de.getId()))
                    .findFirst().get();


            LOG.info("lastDeviceEvent --> " + lastDeviceEvent.getId());
            LOG.info("firstDeviceEvent -> " + firstDeviceEvent.getId());


        } catch (NoSuchElementException nse) {

            throw new AccessDeniedException("403 Forbidden");

        }
```

Comment: what exactly is wrong with the comparator? is it giving a compilation error? is it giving unexpected results? in other words, define "not working".

Comment: After you apply the filter, all device events will have the same ID, so what do you believe sorting ascending by ID will do? Or sorting descending? If you guess what it'll do **nothing**, you'd be guess right, because Java sorts are *stable*: **equal elements will not be reordered** as a result of the sort. Re-think what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparator seems correct. The problem seems to be in your filter clause, where you compare **the event id** to **the device id**

```
lastDeviceEvent = deviceEvents
                .stream()
                .filter (o -> o.getDeviceId().equals(deviceId)) // Original code used getId()
                .sorted(comparing((DeviceEvent de) -> de.getId()).reversed())
                .findFirst()
                .get();
```